# Access dynamic generated radio buttons with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have a MVC Web-Page containing 1 datepicker. After selecting the date, there is an AJAX call to the server providing the user a list of possible actions (being radio buttons)

The user can select a radio button but this cannot be deselected if the user wants.

I tried to fix this with some javascript code, but I cant seem the access those radio buttons when generated dynamically in a partial result by the AJAX call.

It is very important, **the big problem is that the radio buttons are not present on the original form**. and I think therefore I cannot access them.

```
$('#nameofradiobutton') 
$('input[name='nameofradiobutton'])
$('input[type=radio])
$('input')
```

All these and many more are not working not even the last one addressing all input controls...

Any guidelines? starting points? tips? tricks?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please post code of how you are binding radio button

Answer (score 0):

Except for if the DOM element you are trying to access is in an iframe there shouldn't be any reason you can't access it. The only reason I can think of why you can't access it then is because you try to access it before it is added to the page so for example you have your ajax callback call a function `dowork` and it looks like this:

```
function dowork(){

//add the radio buttons 
$('.myradiocontainer').append($('<input type="radio" id="value1" />'));

//you try to check it here but it doesn't work
$('#value1').prop("checked", true);

}
```

If this is the case then you can do this instead:

```
function dowork(){

//add the radio buttons 
$radio1= $('<input type="radio" id="value1" />');
$('.myradiocontainer').append($radio1);

//you try to check it here and it works
$radio1.prop("checked", true); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#parent_element").on("click", "input[name=radio_button]", function(){
    var radio_button = $(this);
});
```

Where parent_element is the parent of your radio button and is not dynamic (present when the dom is loaded). radio_button is the name of radio button. Variable radio_button holds the actual radio button element.